# Glitched start menu in classic theme after removing Windows Search

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, themes

I use the classic theme in Windows 7 (SP1, 64-bit, Ultimate Edition), and have recently uninstalled the Windows Search feature via the control panel since I don't like the search box in the start menu, and in general, it's virtually useless to me (I use Directory Opus anyway). Now that the search box is gone from the start menu, there's a glitch which only appears to be present in the classic theme - not the Basic or Aero themes.

[image: 7 search-less classic start menu bug]

Am I the only one affected? I couldn't find any articles about the phenomenon anywhere. I have of course rebooted the machine (several times) after removing Windows Search, and have tried re-applying the theme, etc.

Lastly, I should mention that I have not installed any updates through Windows Update since I installed the OS, mainly because I'm running it on an offline computer. Additionally, I'm running the OS on VirtualBox (with experimental Direct3D support installed via guest additions), so maybe that could affect it? But I haven't seen any other design/graphical glitches (apart from the lists on grouped taskbar buttons in classic theme, which has extra padding at the top...)